# Can't link with shared library

Tags: macos, gcc, ld, macports

I can't link my program with shared library located in non-standart OSX lib directory. I've got this library from MacPorts and it's located in /opt/local/lib:

```
$ ls /opt/local/lib/libgmp*
/opt/local/lib/libgmp.10.dylib  /opt/local/lib/libgmpxx.4.dylib
/opt/local/lib/libgmp.a         /opt/local/lib/libgmpxx.a
/opt/local/lib/libgmp.dylib     /opt/local/lib/libgmpxx.dylib
/opt/local/lib/libgmp.la        /opt/local/lib/libgmpxx.la
```

I've found that one can use DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH, but it not works for me:

```
$ DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib gcc ab.c -lgmp
ld: library not found for -lgmp
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: try gcc ab.c -L/opt/local/lib -lgmp

Comment: Thanks, it works. Can you convert comment to answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At runtime, DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH helps dynamic linker to locate libraries from non-standard directories.

In your case, you are still in compilation phase.
For gcc to know about these extra directories to search, you could use -L switch.

e.g.

```
gcc ab.c -L/opt/local/lib -lgmp
```